# If the representation part of type abstraction is declared private, then how does sub-classing violate encapsulation?

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance, encapsulation

[Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=3EB7B5E3E3561F9D320347844A78276F?Id=72), I learned that sub-classing violates encapsulation:

> it violates encapsulation, since the implementations of the superclass and subclass become tightly coupled

For instance, If we consider below Java syntax, a `class` has access to all the fields and methods of its super class provided they are not declared `private`.

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    String address;
    //methods of class Person
}

class Employee extends Person{
    float salary;
    private Employee immedateManager;
    private raiseSalary(float raise){...}
}

class Manager extends Employee{
    String department;

    void test(){
        name = "Fred";   //compiler error, could not break encapsulation
        salary = 70000.00f;
        address = "somewhere";
        immediateManager = "Slate"; //compiler error, could not break encapsulation
        raiseSalary(1234.0);    //compiler error, could not break encapsulation
    }
}
```

So, if the representation part of type abstraction (Java `class`) is declared `private`, then how does one understand before saying that, sub-classing violate encapsulation?

Comment: There are two conflicting opinions about this; let me present the one (other posters will undoubtedly present the other): It doesn't violate encapsulation because, per Liskov substitability, the subclass object **is** a superclass object (Herbie IS_A `Car` as well as a `Volkswagen`). Therefore, all the use that herbie makes of the `fuel_tank_volume` value is OK, because it's from *within* the `Car` class and not from without.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with privacy.  An integral part of your class is no longer implemented inside your class.  By definition that's a loss of encapsulation.

However, object-oriented programmers sometimes place an outsized importance on class-level encapsulation.  The other problems with inheritance, such as coupling, are much more important, and the encapsulation loss shouldn't bother you in situations where inheritance is otherwise appropriate.

Comment: For your point: `An integral part of your class is no longer implemented inside your class`. You mean, no longer implemented in sub class? But Liskov principle says:`if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program. This is a test before introducing inheritance.`So, Can't I infer that it is equivalent to implementing in subclass for what you actually implemented in super class?

Comment: Inheritance is certainly appropriate if you need substitutability.  That doesn't mean you aren't trading off some loss of encapsulation, only that you've determined the trade off is worth it.

Comment: when I say,  it is equivalent to implementing in subclass for what you actually implemented in super class. Where is loss of encapsulation here?